# Diffreren behaviour of ProcessBuilder in javac and NetBeands builds

Tags: netbeans, javac, processbuilder

I have a code:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class RunIt{

if (args.length==0) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-Xmx768m","RunIt","anArgument");
    pb.directory(new File("."));            
    try {
        Process process = pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
    System.exit(0);
}
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new classWithJFrameInConstructor();}});
}

import JFrame;

class classWithJFrameInConstructor{
 JFrame frame;

 classWithJFrameInConstructor(){
  frame=new JFrame();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Where classWithJFrameInConstructor is class where JFrame is created and set visible in class constructor

If I compile it normally using `javac` it works well. But if I compile it in NetBeans no windows is run.

The problem part is:

```
System.exit(0);
```

If this code is missing builds from `javac` runs two app windows. Vice versa NetBeans build runs normally.

Comment: Please provide a proper MCVE so that we can test this out for ourselves.

Comment: I would imagine that the classpath would be different

Comment: Possibly.  It could also be in the way he is running the code; e.g. using `java` (or `javaw`) versus from within NetBeans.  Or something like that.  Either way, we need MCVE to figure out what the real issue is here.

Comment: The rest of code is quite complicated thus I have not post it here. But if you run SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new classWithJFrameInConstructor();}}); where classWithJFrameInConstructor is class where JFrame is created and set visible in class constructor at the end of this code it would be  essentially the same what is happening further in real code.

Comment: So if it is "essesentially the same" ... why don't you create a MCVE that implements that "essentially the same" behavior?  Do you want help, or don't you?

Comment: Yes, of course, I do. I have created MCVE as you said.

Comment: Probably the problem origin is the same as I am unraveling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158652/java-continues-application-run.