# JAVA - continues application run

Tags: java, executable-jar, processbuilder

I have the following code.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-xmx768m","DesDatMain","anArgument"); 
    pb.directory(new File("."));        
    try{
        Process process = pb.start();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new JFrame();}});
}
```

If I run it in “home” folder (containing source files etc.) it will continuously run one app by one app. The same result has executable jar. But if I move this jar to another location it simple runs one window.

**Inserted:**

Maybe it will be helpful to know that if I have this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 if(args.length==0){ 
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-Xmx768m","DesDatMain","anArgument");
  pb.directory(new File("."));      
  try{Process process = pb.start();}
  catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}.                       
  System.exit(0);
 }

 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new JFrame();}});
}
```

and it si run either using java.exe or jar file in “home” directory it is normally run but if I move jar to another location no windows is run.

Comment: Sounds like there is something missing. Have you tried building a fat jar containing all dependencies?

Comment: try adding your `jar` to the codepath `java -cp <yourjarname> [...]`

Comment: Do you have your classpath set up?

Comment: It is probably the same issue as I described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015537/diffreren-behaviour-of-processbuilder-in-javac-and-netbeands-builds.

Comment: Nick L: By the classpath you mean path to java.exe in system path, isn't it right? If it is I of course have set it up.

Comment: BeyelerStudios: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Patrick Weiß: I am not using tools capable of building fat jars.

Comment: you run it first in the jar folder and second time from the folder without jar?

Comment: AdamSkywalker: No. First time using java.exe or jar file in folder with source files and second time in any other location from jar file.